# I downgraded the instance size of my Wordpress GCE instance, the new instance doesnt seem to be running properly

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance on which I was running a `g1-small` instance that hosted a wordpress site.

I wanted to downgrade the instance size to `f1-micro`, so I

a) stopped the instancce
b) edited the instance and changed it's size to `f1-micro`
c) started the instance

Unfortunately when the instance restarted, the wordpress site does not seem to be loading. SSH-ing into the instance reveals that Apache & MySQL are running, but visiting the newly generated external IP in the browser doesn't load the website.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Sorry for details that might not have been specified well, super new to GCP & wordpress.

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the behavior you're seeing when trying to load the site and any relevant logging in the Apache/MySQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your issue is **`f1-micro` doesn't have enough resources to run LAMP**.

If you compare `f1-micro` and `g1-small` you'll see that `f1-micro` provides you significantly less resources even than `g1-small`. I do not recommend to use `f1-micro` for any production tasks. Have a look at the documentation [N1 shared-core machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_shared-core_machine_types) to get more information:

[image: machine_type]

You can slightly improve situation by shutting down some services like [Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent) `google-fluentd` that preinstalled to VMs or any other unnecessary services, but I'd rather switch back to `g1-small`.

In addition, you can try some images from Market place like [openlitespeed-wordpress](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/wordpress/) that offers preconfigured solution based on `f1-micro`.